# python executable file across different platforms

Tags: python, windows

I need to write a python file, make it executable and be able to execute it on Windows and Unix.

For example, I place

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

at the top of "foo.py". I chmod foo.py to be executable.

This runs fine on Unix.

On Windows, it gives the following error

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘python3’ No such file or directory
```

If I replace "python3" with "python" in "#!/usr/bin/env python3", the executable will work on Windows.

My question is 
"Can I find a way to make the execytable foo.py run on diferent platforms without the need to manually replace "python3" with "python"?" For reference, I am attaching below an answer to such issue by @Christian Witts

"The Windows installation of Python 3.x does not have an executable called python3 unlike *nix which does. If you change your shebang line to #!/usr/bin/env python it will use the Python that is installed."

Comment: You can name these executables anything you want. Indeed, it *should* be just `python`. For me, `/usr/bin/env python` *is* a Python 3 executable.

Comment: Have you considered of using some `.exe` file? Suh as `pyinstaller` or `py2exe`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you for your comment. I know you can do that. But my goal is to to find an automated way to detect and handle this situation. If, for example, my file is going to be used by others, then each person should manually change their executable.

Comment: @AmarthGûl Thank you for your comment. I am afraid I am not familiar with pyinstaller and py2exe. I'll try to read about them.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you.  Yes, it's "python" on Windows but "python3" on Unix. I need a trick to be able to run on both environments without manually editing the "#!/usr/bin/env python" at the top of the file.

Comment: I tried to come up with a solution based on Perl's funky shebang syntax shown here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20880/how-can-i-use-environment-variables-in-my-shebang/20926#20926 and here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450509/could-someone-explain-this-shebang-line-which-uses-sh-and-then-does-exec-perl but I was not able to come up with something that solves your problem. This starts right but fails with a syntax error in python, maybe someone can improve on it? `#!/bin/bash` followed by 
`exec \`which python3 2> /dev/null; which python 2> /dev/null\` "$0" "$@"`

Comment: If you tell py.exe to search `PATH` via `env`, it won't find "python3.exe" for a default installation in Windows. The launcher does support `#!/usr/bin/python3`, if you can use that instead. Alternatively, you could distribute this script as a wheel package that can be pip installed to the `--user` scripts/bin directory. (In Windows it's not in `PATH` by default, so you'll need instructions to add it.) If you define an entrypoint function, pip creates a wrapper executable that runs Python, imports your module, and calls your entrypoint as the main function.

Comment: @joanis Thank you for your time. I am not sure I can improve it. I am a beginner!

Comment: @eryksun Thank you for your note. Please note that I am a beginner. Could you please tell me how can I tell py.exe to search PATH via env?

Comment: I said that's what you're already doing with `#!/usr/bin/env python3`, and it won't work since there is no "python3.exe" to be found. The py launcher does support virtual Unix paths, however, such as `#!/usr/bin/python3`. This will run the highest version of Python 3 that it finds installed in the registry under "[HKLM|HKCU]\Software[\WOW6432Node]\Python\PythonCore".